# Does the iOS SDK allow you to insert audio into the conversation?

Tags: ios

More specifically, does the iOS SDK allow you to insert programatic audio (background noise) into a conversation that both the caller and receiver can hear?

Answer (score 0):

No it does not. Apple does not allow third party apps to interfere with phone calls in any way.